# How do I provide a substring then extract the number before it in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, gsub

I have a column with a few numbers and strings and I am trying to provide R with the substring "sst" and then extracting the number that appears before it.

```
df1 <- structure (list(
  subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", "191-0987", "191-1245", "191-1945"), 
 bloods = c("2 SST, 1 EDTA","1 EDTA 2 sst","1SST, 2 EDTA","2 EDTA, 1SST collected","2SST, 1EDTA","1 EDTA")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Desired output:

| subject_id | bloods | num_sst |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 191-5467 | 2 SST, 1 EDTA | 2 |
| 191-6784 | 1 EDTA 2 sst | 2 |
| 191-3457 | 1SST, 2 EDTA | 1 |
| 191-0987 | 2 EDTA, 1SST collected | 1 |
| 191-1245 | 2SST, 1EDTA | 2 |
| 191-1945 | 1 EDTA | 0 |

I know how to exact all numbers from each row but because there is no specific pattern it would be difficult to see which number was for sst.

Please kindly assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `str_extract` to extract the number before "SST" string.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(num_sst = str_extract(bloods, "(\\d+)\\s?(?i)SST", group = 1),
         num_sst = replace(num_sst, is.na(num_sst), 0))

#  subject_id                 bloods num_sst
#1   191-5467          2 SST, 1 EDTA       2
#2   191-6784           1 EDTA 2 sst       2
#3   191-3457           1SST, 2 EDTA       1
#4   191-0987 2 EDTA, 1SST collected       1
#5   191-1245            2SST, 1EDTA       2
#6   191-1945                 1 EDTA       0
```

where `(\\d+)` extract one or more digit followed by an optional whitespace (`\\s?`) optional because not every number is followed by a space and since "SST" is case insensitive i.e it can be either "SST" or "sst" so we use the case insensitive flag (`?i`) for it.

If there are no digits satisfying the condition `str_extract` returns `NA` since you need 0 for them we use `replace` to replace the `NA`'s with 0.

Comment: How do I edit this to account for one and two whitespaces?

Comment: You may use the pattern `str_extract(bloods, "(\\d+)(\\s+)?(?i)SST", group = 1)`